# How to convert different dates formats to a unified format?

Tags: python, date, datetime, type-conversion, datetime-format

Answers dates on Quora have different formats depending on the answer age , when an answer date is from the current week, only day abbreviation is mentionned (ex: 'mon'). When it is from the current year, only day and month abbreviation are mentionned (ex: 'Mar 29'). When it is from a different year, the date is like 'Jan 19, 2017'.

Is there a module in python that handle all this cases, so that dates are converted into a unified format like :'YYYY-MM-DD' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [`dateparser`](https://github.com/scrapinghub/dateparser):

```
>>> dateparser.parse("13m ago") # relative to your system's local timezone
datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 8, 22, 48, 15, 273673) 
>>> dateparser.parse("Mon")
datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 3, 0, 0)
>>> dateparser.parse("Mar 29")
datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 29, 0, 0)
>>> dateparser.parse("Jan 19, 2017")
datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 19, 0, 0)
```

If you need them in the `YYYY-MM-DD` format, you can just convert them back into a string:

```
>>> dateparser.parse("Jan 19, 2017").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
'2017-01-19'
```